# How to open search/find dialog in jqGrid from an external button?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid which has a "find" button - this brings up the jqGrid's filter dialog where I can filter stuff - cool. How can I trigger that dialog to open from a button that is not a part of the jqGrid control?

I've found that I can do this: `$("#id").trigger('reloadGrid');` to tell the grid to go get the data again and rebuild the jqGrid UI. Is there something similar, like `$("#id").trigger('openFindDialog');`?

Answer (score 5):

jqGrid has [searchGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching) method which you need to use. To open the searching dialog you should call the method and use any parameters or events which you probably knows from the previous usage of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#how_to_use):

```
$("#id").jqGrid ('searchGrid', {multipleSearch:true, overlay: false});
```

How you can see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.0.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L1780) the code which are running on click on the "Search" button of the navigator is not much more as this.