# How to open Edit like form using custom data in jqGrid?

Tags: forms, jqgrid, edit

I'm using jqGrid on lot of pages, but on some pages, which are not using jqgrid I want to show Edit like form to maintain look and feel consistency.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629762/how-to-open-search-find-dialog-in-jqgrid-from-an-external-button) talks about something similar but those pages have jqgrid table.

Basically, I'm wondering if its possible to open jqGrid add/edit/view form (without defining full table) using my custom row data? Additionally, since these forms are on new pages, I want to show them as a regular form, not in modal.

**Edit:**

One possibility I see : I can create a dummy table and hide it and generate form but this would open form in a modal, I guess. Last option could be applying jqGrid css to my forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the form editing in a part of jqGrid I would recommend you, like you already mention in your question, to create a hidden jqGrid to use form `editGridRow` method. The data of the grid can be filled with respect of `data` parameter and the grid should has `datatype:'local'`. At least the structures like `colModel`, `colNames` and so on. To be more sure that your code will continue work in the next version of jqGrid creating a hidden grid is better as creating some dummy structures.

So the main question is "How to create add/edit/view form which are **not modal**?". To do this you can use the following Add/Edit/View options

```
jqModal:false,
afterShowForm:function(){
    $("#lui_"+grid[0].id).hide(); // hide overlay like "#lui_list"
}
```

where `grid` is jQuery wrapper of your grid/table: `var grid = $("#list")`.