# How to render jqgrid edit form without grid

Tags: jqgrid

Settings table contains always one row with lot of long-caption columns.
Opening this in jqGrid grid looks ugly.

How to force jqGrid to render its edit form instead of grid ?
In edit form data can changed and saved, grid is not nessecary.
Grid caption bar is not used (caption is empty string) and top level toolbar is used.
Row is loaded from server using json call.
I tried to use Oleg answer from [How to open Edit like form using custom data in jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323225/how-to-open-edit-like-form-using-custom-data-in-jqgrid)

```
 grid.jqGrid({
   gridstate: 'hidden',
   loadComplete: function() { 
     $("#edit_grid_top").click();
     $("#lui_"+$('#grid').id).hide();
     }
...
```

Edit form opens, but grid is still visible. How to render edit form without grid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe too late, but nevertheless:

You have to hide your grid programatically. My solution was (for a grid with lots of columns):

```
<div id="detailslistWrapper">
    <table id="detailslist">
        <tr> <td/> </tr>          
    </table>
    <div id="detailspager"></div>
</div>
```

and after that:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#detailslistWrapper").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work as: `$("#gview_"+gridid).hide()`